# Impossible to read a VHD file

Tags: vhd

I've been given a job: open a `XXXX.vhd` file and extract datas from an SQL folder.
The problem is that I've tried this:

- install "WMWare" then open it. "File unknown" as a result.
- install "Oracle VM VirtualBox" then open it. "File unknown" as a result.
- install "VHD Attach" then right click => attach then i go to the "`Disk manager`" and here's the problem, when I right-click on it: all possibilities are greyed. Why? What could be the solution?

[image: Disk Manager greyed menu]

As a hint, I've been told there has something to do with Linux.

Any idea?

Comment: What exactly has something to do with Linux?  If you don't provide us more information we can't really help. The only reason you wouldn't be able to attach and view the contents of a .VHD file within Windows 7 is because the version your using doesn't support it.  **You should have no problem using Virtual PC and loading up the actual operating system to access the data you want.  If you want to use VMWare then convert the image.**

Comment: "If you want to use VMWare then convert the image.". Thank you, I'll search for this on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly there's an ext2/ext3/ext4 partition on that disk. Windows only supports FAT and NTFS partitions. ext is an Linux partitions format, so you need Linux to read it - or maybe [Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs) or [Ext2explore](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/Ext2Read%20ver%202.0/ext2explore%202.0%20beta/) will do the job.

Comment: `explore2fs-1.08beta9` didn't work

Comment: Then give Ext2explore a try. Explore2fs doesn't support the latest ext4 format.

Comment: I've tried. This doesn't work, but it showed that there are 3 partitions: the first one (102Mb) it ext3, the second is "RAW" and third is "RAW" too. If I have to go under Linux how should I do? Which program? Thank you for your answer

Comment: "Raw" format should be taken literally - there's no file system on that partition or it's corrupted. Or maybe VHD is corrupted and it's the reason why VM software can't even touch it and what other apps show doesn't make any sense. Try attaching original file, as this copy may have been changed by VMware or VirtualBox. Also, Ext2explore is capable of opening some drive images - maybe it could handle VHD. Also, it looks like 7-Zip can open those too.

Answer (score 1):

Use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) to open that VHD. It opens all VHDs that I have.
If it has Linux partitions, then you can try [Paragon Ext](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/) driver for Windows it supports Ext2/3/4 partitions. Also try Linux live distros like Ubuntu Live.

However you mentioned that VMWare couldn't open it.
Maybe image was damaged? Or maybe it has such unknown file system that even VMWare can't recognize it?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 Enterprise and Ultimate editions support VHD, both with and without a host operating system present. You should be able to use the file on those systems.